# ActiveMQ CMS: Is there a way to use it without threading?

Tags: multithreading, activemq-cpp

I took the sample code from Apache here: https://activemq.apache.org/components/cms/example

(The producer section specfically) and tried to rewrite it so it doesn't create any threads for producing. And instead, in my program's main thread, creates a producer object and sets up the connection, session, destination, and so on. Then it sends messages using a message producer. This is all done in a singleton so that my program just has one Producer object and just goes to it whenever it needs to dump any message to one of my queues. This example code seems to create a producer for every thread, set it up everytime, just to send a message, then deletes everything. And it does this for every time you want to want to produce something from your program.

I am crashing right when I try to call send on a message producer with any given message. I found out after some digging that after the send call it tries to lock a mutex and enter a critical section. I guess this is for threading? I don't use threads at all in my code so I guess it crashes because of that... Does anyone know a way to bypass this? I don't want to use multiple threads, I won't need to worry about two threads trying to call send at the same time or whatever the problem is that using mutexes is trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a thread to run the producer in but internally the library is going to use a couple of threads as that is necessary for meeting the API requirements and also just because you don't use multiple threads doesn't means others won't so the mutex is an internal requirement.

You are free to modify the example to only create a producer inside the main thread of the application, the example uses two threads because it is acting as both a producer and consumer.

One likely cause of the error you are receiving is because you did not initialize the ActiveMQ-CPP library:

```
activemq::library::ActiveMQCPP::initializeLibrary();
```

Comment: This was it. I figured it out yesterday with the help of a friend. It turns out I had forgotten that my ActiveMQ consumer code was still running, which uses the exact same initializeLibrary call and so when it would finish, it would call shutdownLibrary, and the producer code would crash because it wasn't reinitialized. Had me stuck forever.